# Do the static (class) variables necessarily have to be const?

Tags: c++

I tried compiling this in visual studio:

```
class A {
    int a;
    static int b = 0;
    public:
        A(int x) { a = x; }
        void changeA(int x) { a = x; }
        int getA() { return a; }
};
```

And it gives me the following error:

> error C2864: 'A::b' : a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type

What seems to be the problem officer?

Comment: Remove `= 0;` and put `int A::b = 0;` after the class definition and in a source file.

Comment: Why does it have to be after the class definition?

Comment: Because that's just the rules. It may be different in C++11, I can't remember.

Comment: It's different than Java too. I though it would be similar, but it's obviously not.

Comment: So, what are the rules? If it's const, it can be initialized in the class definition, is it?

Comment: If it's a const and certain types such as integers, yes.